# transformers pretrained model's accuracy decreases after fine-tuning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I am using a pre-trained model from hugging face (distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english) for sentiment analysis (binary classification of text).

Right after compiling it, I evaluate it using part of my dataset and get 80% accuracy. However, I try to fine-tune it using the fit function and all I achieve is decreasing its accuracy from 80% down to 51%.

Here're some basic parts of the code and their outputs:

```
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels=2, from_pt=True)
model.compile(optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5), loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False), metrics=["accuracy"])
model.evaluate(test_dataset)

# 63/63 [==============================] - 1039s 16s/step - loss: 7.4712 - accuracy: 0.8090

model.fit(train_dataset,epochs=1,batch_size=16)

# 63/63 [==============================] - 3392s 54s/step - loss: 7.6672 - accuracy: 0.5280

model.evaluate(test_dataset)

# 63/63 [==============================] - 999s 16s/step - loss: 7.6675 - accuracy: 0.5120
```

I am new to this but by reading some [tutorials](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#compile-and-fit) I understood that using `fit` would take the already trained model and compute some more epochs with the new data to fine-tune it.

I first thought that maybe my data was not properly pre-processed, but given the high accuracy of the first evaluation it seeed strange. Could it be that the original model is able to classify my maybe-not-perfectly-processed data due to some key words/features that make the task easy but once I try to train the model further, I damage it by making it learn from said data?

If necessary, I can add more code.

**UPDATE**:

Preprocessing: I remove weird characters, downcase everything, remove stopwords and lemmatize.
Then I use AutoTokenizer with the same model I am trying to autotune. I take a subset of the data so it does not take so long.

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
train_encodings = tokenizer(list(train_text_data),truncation=True,padding=True)
train_dataset = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encodings), list(train_labels)))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).take(1000).batch(16)
```

PD: I also wonder why it takes so long to only evaluate the model. I'd understand if it was a seq2seq model but with the ANNs I'm used to, predicting/evaluating for classification is pretty straightforward.

Comment: you are using a pre-trained transformer-based modal for what? what happens when you fine-tune the modal using your data? does the embedding layer also change? that would mean contextual relevance between words will change. what kind of pre-processing have you done?

Comment: @RitwickJha added the info on the question. I'm using it for sentiment analysis (binary classification of text)

Comment: Hi, just to clarify you are using distil bert alone for classification? is there no softmax layer on top?. BERT is insanely large modal. each token is coded using 768 scalars, that is the embedding for each token is a 768 long vector, if you have 10k sentencess with 70 tokens each, that is dimensionality of 10k*70*768. you can understand why it will run so slow.

Comment: so to do simple sentiment analysis we can just use a special token (the first token for each sentence is [CLS]) which will in some sense capture the sentiment of the whole sentence rather than using num_tokens*768 input, the input to softmax would just be 768 embedding for [CLS]. you should definitely do that. also read up on how attention works in transformers, it is quite an expensive operation. check this out https://jalammar.github.io/a-visual-guide-to-using-bert-for-the-first-time/

Comment: @RitwickJha I'll try what you suggest but it's part of a university task so I'd like to get this version working as well, even if it is slow. So.. any idea why the accuracy decreases so much?

Comment: well the pre-trained aspect of bert as far as i know is only in the embedding layer, that is the representation of tokens as vectors. when you fone tune it, the representation will change. bert has some sense of context and some sense of a language modal which is derived from a huge corpus that is to say it understands english kind of well. when you fine tune it the context will become biased to what is seen in the training set. it is only a guess.